# How can an instance variable in the same Python object seemingly reference different objects at the same time?

Tags: python, reference, identity, arcpy

I have two parameter lists `[{Parameter(arcpy.Parameter)}]` and `[{arcpy.Parameter}]`. The subclass `Parameter` contains additional attributes and functions when compared to the base class `arcpy.Parameter`.

Below is the output from the debug console. `param` is in list 1 and `param2` is in list 2. The filter object is referenced in the base class by  the class variable `filter`. Changes to `param.filter` should also take effect on `param2.filter` and vice versa, since they should refer to the same instance.

```
id(param)
86840096L
id(param2)
86840096L
id(param.filter)
62961424L
id(param2.filter)
62961368L
```

Why can the filter ids differ at the same time although the param ids are the same? What does that imply? Can I prevent (or just ignore) this?

```
class Parameter(mixins.ParameterMixin,_BaseArcObject):
    filter = passthrough_attr('filter')
...

class Filter(_BaseArcObject):
    """The filter object allows you to specify the choices available for a
       parameter."""
    type = passthrough_attr('type')
    list = passthrough_attr('list')

def passthrough_attr(prop):
    "Basic attribute passthrough for a wrapped Arc object -- allows for early binding."
    def get_(self):
        "Geoprocessor %s property" % prop
        return getattr(self._arc_object, prop)
    def set_(self, val):
        return setattr(self._arc_object, prop, val)
    return property(get_, set_)

class _BaseArcObject(object):
    _arc_object = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Wrapper for ArcGIS scripting Arc Objects --
           Create a new object instance if no reference is passed in."""
        super(_BaseArcObject, self).__init__()
        self._arc_object = gp._gp.CreateObject(self.__class__.__name__,
                    *((arg._arc_object if hasattr(arg, '_arc_object') else arg)
                        for arg in args))
...
```

Comment: Is `.filter` a property that returns a different object each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a wild guess, if `filter` is a method, those are created on the fly from functions *each time you access them*.

```
>>> class A:
...    def foo(self):
...        pass
    
>>> type(A.foo)
function
>>> id(A.foo)
2528402192848
>>> id(A.foo)
2528402192848
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a.foo)
method
>>> id(a.foo)
2528397338368
>>> id(a.foo)
2528397337664
```

Note that the last two ids differ.

Comment: I don't think so. Documentation: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/filter.htm

Comment: @Zeygon please be a bit more specific. You could also just look into the source code what kind of object `filter` is. It has to be something that is created on the fly when you access it.

Comment: You must be right. The object id changes, when I call id() multiple times. Not always though. The full implementation is a little hard to grasp at least for me (see above). But your answer is sufficient for me.